# VB.NET Updating database table using dataset

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, dataset

I am trying to update my physical database using a dataset. There is no error that appears but the Table in my Database doesn't updating at all.

I am using VS 2012, VB.NET

This is my code for updating my database table name "ProdRec"

```
    grid()
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Update(ds, "ProdRec")
    ds.AcceptChanges()
```

I declare my dataset named "ds" in this Public sub

```
    Public Sub grid()
     connect()
     MD = "Select * From ProdRec"
     com = New OleDbCommand(MD, conn)
     adaptr = New OleDbDataAdapter(com)
     ds = New DataSet
       adaptr.Fill(ds, "ProdRec")

     With DataGridView1()
    .DataSource = ds
    .DataMember = "ProdRec"
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this before da.Update command:  `da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand()`

Comment: Hi @IVAAAN123 an error occurred when I try this one. "The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized."

Comment: oh, yeah. So try to set your select command "Select * From ProdRec"

Comment: Another Problem appeared @IVAAAN123 it says "Conversion from string "SELECT * FROM [ProdRec]" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."   
I did it this way
`Dim SelectProdRec As String = "SELECT * FROM [ProdRec]"`

Then 

`da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand(SelectProdRec)`

Comment: A big big THANK YOU @IVAAAN123  Maraming Salamat :D